# Is there any file chooser or gallery which will show predefined image so user will select one image from it in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, kendo-ui-angular2

**Is there any file chooser or gallery which will show a server's predefined images so the user will select one image from it in angular?**

For example like the **MS-Word symbol gallery** we can select one symbol, I have attached a screenshot of the same.[image: ms-word symbol gallery]

Comment: you can use `ngx-gallery` [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-gallery) and click event listener for images to perform further operations.